# How to avoid duplicate jakarta classes with fat jakartaee-api jar and individual api jars like ws.rs-api?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

Most 3rd party libraries I've seen pull in individual API spec artifacts, like `jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api`. Some however depend on `jakartaee-api` (or similar) "fat" jars, that package the very same classes as the individual API spec jars.

This creates a maintenance hell, as it is very easy to end up with multiple versions of the same class on classpath - one coming from `jakartaee-api` and one coming from `ws.rs-api`. If the versions don't match, there's no telling which classes will actually be used at runtime, possibly leading to `NoSuchMethodError`s and so on.

What is the recommended way to pull in `jakarta` API artifacts, if I'm not using a JavaEE application server (e.g. Wildfly)? When dealing with 3rd party libs, should I exclude the individual API spec transitional artifacts, or should I exclude the "fat" full-spec jars?